# Movement of a sprite according to rotation

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, geometry, trigonometry

I hope this is an acceptable question for this forum, as it's more of a maths question than a programming question.

I am developing a basic space shooter game using the cocos2d framework, where the user controls a spaceship and shoots asteroids/enemies, and the enemies also shoot back at the spaceship (original eh?).

The 'lasers' that are fired by the enemies are a tube like shape, and generally only travel form right to left on the x axis.  This is easy to achieve, and the movement is created with this line of code:

```
currentEnemyProjectile.position = ccp(currentEnemyProjectile.position.x - ((screenSize.width/kLaserSpeed)* dtSixty), currentEnemyProjectile.position.y);
```

I also have one particular enemy, which resides in the middle of the screen and rotates to fire its projectiles at the spaceship, so if the space ship is at a different y position than the enemy then the projectile sprite will be rotated and then will move to the spaceship's position, so it will need to also move through the y axis.

I'm currently using code to achieve this:

```
float xDiff = ((screenSize.width/kLaserSpeed)* dtSixty);
float yDiff = (xDiff / 57) * currentEnemyProjectile.rotation;

currentEnemyProjectile.position = ccp(currentEnemyProjectile.position.x - xDiff, currentEnemyProjectile.position.y + yDiff);
```

I just worked this out as a temporary fix, I know it is not the optimal way of doing things.  It sort of works, but as I am working out the y offset from the movement along the x axis, the projectiles will move faster if they have further to travel along the y axis.  Ideally they should move slower along the x axis if they are moving further upwards or downwards, so that the rate of travel is constant for any trajectory. (I hope I've explained that well enough)

It's been roughly 10 years since I last had a maths lesson, so my geometry/trigonometry is rather hazy/non-existent, can anyone shed any light on how this can be done?

Also, it's worth noting that I would like to do this without the use of cocos2d actions.  I would rather move my sprites each frame as I have been currently doing as I manipulating the flow of time as part of the game, so I need more control than the cocos2d actions can offer.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm a little confused by your variables.  kLaserSpeed should be in units of distance/second. Is dtSixty something like delta time for a 60Hz clock rate?  Why is xDiff dependent on the screen width?  All you have to do is multiply velocity*dt to get the distance moved, call it "d", along the hypotenuse of the triangle. So, dx = d*sin(angle) and dy = d*cos(angle).  Make sure you check for the appropriate sign.

Comment: The reason I am dividing screen width by kLaserSpeed is that this will give me a constant gameplay experience across different devices (iPhone 4/iPhone 5/ipad), for instance if kLaser speed is 500, then the object will travel 1/500th width of the screen, independent of screen size. dtSixty is just the time since the last frame multiplied by sixty.  I had originally started the project without adjusting for the current frame rate, so when I wanted to do that later, as it was running a 60 fps, if I multiplied the time since the last frame by 60, I could keep the same figures for the speed.

Comment: I'll have a look at the equation you game me and see if I can get it to work, I think I could do with brushing up on my trigonometry a bit! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find a position using a starting position, an angle, and a distance, the formula is as follows:

```
ccp( x + ( distance * sin( angle ) ), y + ( distance * cos( angle) ) )
```

Keep in mind that the angle for this formula will have to be in radians, not degrees. You can convert degrees into radians like this:

```
radians = degrees * PI / 180
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  I realized since you know the vector to the player, you don't need the trig.  You only need to calculate v and h once so you may want to save those values and not calculate them on every frame.

```
// Vector from enemy to player
CGPoint v = enemy.position - player.position;

// distance from enemy to player (sqrt of the dot product of v with v)
float h = sqrt(v.x*v.x+v.y*v.y);

// Desired distance to move along v
delta = ((screenSize.width/kLaserSpeed)* dtSixty);

// delta/h is the % moved along v, find the % moved in the x and y direction 
xDiff = v.x * delta/h;
yDiff = v.y * delta/h;
```